# Full screen mode not working for tc

Tags: windows-7, c

I am using a windows 7 os. I am assigned by my instructor to write a C program to draw a circle. I was asked to do it using turbo c. Now, I have installed tc from an old cd of mine. When I open my **C:\TC\BIN\TC**, the following window appears.

[image: '16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem' - window]

What should I need to do to open my tc in full screen mode? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: TC does'not supports windows 7 in fullscreen mode!
is this 64bit windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turbo C++ by yogisoft](http://www.techblix.com/download-full-screen-turbo-c-c-for-windows-7-windows-8-32bit64bit-working/) seems better than DosBox to work with tc in full screen mode.

It involves only one download and one installation whereas the DosBox mechanism needs two downloads, two installations and some more command line stuffs.

Do remember! This is a better answer only for the query posted. But for growing programmers, it is always far better to move on to the modern compilers as in [Cornelius' recommendations](https://superuser.com/questions/775125/full-screen-mode-not-working-for-tc/775127#775127).

Comment: The problem with this is that any application built with Turbo C may not work natively with most recent Windows, due to the age of the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Turbo C is an obsolete application. It is 16-bit and it is not supported in full-screen mode since Windows Vista. It doesn't run at all on 64-bit systems!

I would recommend you try a modern compiler with IDE:

- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) with GCC
- [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) with GCC

If you still want to stick to Turbo C, you could use an emulator like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to [run it in fullscreen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_9AKXeBBw). [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbocforwindows-9/) is a custom setup of DOSBox with Turbo C included.

Comment: I would like to add the following: the reason behind Turbo C is to draw a circle. The `graphics.h` header file isn't standard and only present in Turbo C. To replace it in modern compilers, use [WinBGIm](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) for MinGW. Also, I would stray from Dev-C++ as it hasn't been updated recently, instead use it's offspring project, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/)